# Compare two lists of hasmaps in java unittests

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, hashmap

What is the most efficient way how to assert in (java, spring) unittests that these two lists of hashmaps are equal?

```
list1 = [{COUNT=5, AUTHOR=William Shakespare}, {COUNT=1, AUTHOR= Mark Helprin}]
list2 = [{AUTHOR=Mark Helprin, COUNT=1}, {AUTHOR=William Shakespare, COUNT=5}]
```

I am testing a DAO method (if there are 2 books with the same title in the db, it will count how many entries belong to which author and return a list of maps with the names and counts)

the original DAO method

```
    public List<Map<String, Object>> countQuotesByAuthor(String title) {
    return jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT author, COUNT(*) as count FROM Quote WHERE title = ? GROUP BY author",
            new Object[] { title });
}
```

the test method (does not consider the list1 and list2 as equal)

```
    @Test
public void testCountQuotesByAuthor() throws Exception {
    List<Map<String, Object>> counts = QuoteDAOImpl.countQuotesByAuthor("Winter's Tale");
    for (Map<String, Object> count : counts) {
        Object aut = ((String) count.get("AUTHOR")).trim();
        count.put("AUTHOR", aut);
    }

    List<Map<String, Object>> result =  new ArrayList<>();
     Map<String,Object> shake=new HashMap<>();
     shake.put("AUTHOR", "William Shakespeare");
     shake.put("COUNT","2");

     Map<String,Object> help=new HashMap<>();
     help.put("AUTHOR", "Mark Helprin");
     help.put("COUNT","1");

     result.add(shake);
     result.add(help);

     Assert.assertTrue(new HashSet<>(result).equals(new HashSet<>(counts)));
}
```

I get error message

```
java.lang.AssertionError
at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:87)
at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:42)
at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:53)
at com.quotes.QuoteIntegrationTest.testCountQuotesByAuthor(QuoteIntegrationTest.java:86)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:43)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:82)
at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

Comment: 1) Tell what methods you considered. 2) Explain why you think they are not efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you mean by efficient, but if "efficient" means "quickly implemented" here are some quick options.

If you know you don't have duplicates (two identical maps in one or the other list) you can convert those Lists to Sets and then use equals:

```
new HashSet<>(list1).equals(new HashSet<>(list2))
```

If you know at least one of them won't have duplicates, additionally check the sizes are the same.

If you may have duplicates in both, you could use Guava's `MultiSet`s.

Comment: but this does not seem to work for:

`result = [{COUNT=2, AUTHOR=William Shakespeare}, {COUNT=1, AUTHOR=Mark Helprin}];
counts = [{AUTHOR=Mark Helprin, COUNT=1}, {AUTHOR=William Shakespeare, COUNT=2}];

Assert.assertTrue(new HashSet<>(result).equals(new HashSet<>(counts)));`

I get

`java.lang.AssertionError
 at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:87)
 at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:42)
 at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:53)
 at com.quotes.QuoteIntegrationTest.testCountQuotesByAuthor(QuoteIntegrationTest.java:86)`

Comment: I suspect a mismatch between object type. For instance maybe the 1 and 2 in your `counts` map are `Integer`s, and you are comparing them with `String`s. In particular I'm wondering why you declared those maps to be `Map<String, Object>` instead of `Map<String, String>` as you're only putting `String` values in them. Note how `"2".equals(2)` will return false, Java doesn't convert types automaticaly like, say, Javascript. However when you print the objects with `toString` (like in your comment above) then both appear as `"2"` so you can't see the difference there.

Comment: yes! thank you - I am testing the result of jdbc template query for map which only returns List<Map<String,Object>> (like [here](https://riptutorial.com/spring/example/25386/query-for-list-of-maps))